# Ignore byte-order marks in C++, reading from a stream

Tags: c++, unicode

I have a function to read the value of one variable (integer, double, or boolean) on a single line in an `ifstream`:

```
template <typename Type>
void readFromFile (ifstream &in, Type &val)
{
  string str;
  getline (in, str);
  stringstream ss(str);
  ss >> val;
}
```

However, it fails on text files created with editors inserting a BOM ([byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)) at the beginning of the first line, which unfortunately includes {Note,Word}pad. How can I modify this function to ignore the byte-order mark if present at the beginning of `str`?

Comment: You mean the UTF-8 BOM? That's very arcane...

Comment: Ahem.. UTF8 BOM isn't FEFF EF BB BF it's supposed to be endian agnostic too. btw the UTF8 BOM is poo-pooed by the unicode consortium.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

(I'm assuming you're on Windows, since using U+FEFF as a signature in UTF-8 files is mostly a Windows thing and should simply be avoided elsewhere)

You could open the file as a UTF-8 file and then check to see if the first character is U+FEFF. You can do this by opening a normal char based fstream and then use wbuffer_convert to treat it as a series of code units in another encoding. VS2010 doesn't yet have great support for char32_t so the following uses UTF-16 in wchar_t.

```
std::fstream fs(filename);
std::wbuffer_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>,wchar_t> wb(fs.rdbuf());
std::wistream is(&wb);
// if you don't do this on the stack remember to destroy the objects in reverse order of creation. is, then wb, then fs.
std::wistream::int_type ch = is.get();
const std::wistream::int_type ZERO_WIDTH_NO_BREAK_SPACE = 0xFEFF
if(ZERO_WIDTH_NO_BREAK_SPACE != ch)
    is.putback(ch);

// now the stream can be passed around and used without worrying about the extra character in the stream.

int i;
readFromStream<int>(is,i);
```

Remember that this should be done on the file stream as a whole, not inside readFromFile on your stringstream, because ignoring U+FEFF should only be done if it's the very first character in the whole file, if at all. It shouldn't be done anywhere else.

On the other hand, if you're happy using a char based stream and just want to skip U+FEFF if present then James Kanze suggestion seems good so here's an implementation:

```
std::fstream fs(filename);
char a,b,c;
a = fs.get();
b = fs.get();
c = fs.get();
if (a != (char)0xEF || b != (char)0xBB || c != (char)0xBF) {
    fs.seekg(0);
} else {
    std::cerr << "Warning: file contains the so-called 'UTF-8 signature'\n";
}
```

---

Additionally if you want to use `wchar_t` internally the `codecvt_utf8_utf16` and `codecvt_utf8` facets have a mode that can consume 'BOMs' for you. The only problem is that `wchar_t` is widely recognized to be worthless these days* and so you probably shouldn't do this.

```
std::wifstream fin(filename);
fin.imbue(std::locale(fin.getloc(), new std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10FFFF, std::consume_header));
```

<sub>* `wchar_t` is worthless because it is specified to do just one thing; provide a fixed size data type that can represent any code point in a locale's character repertoire. It does not provide a common representation *between* locales (i.e., the same `wchar_t` value can be different characters in different locales so you cannot necessarily convert to `wchar_t`, switch to another locale, and then convert back to `char` in order to do `iconv`-like encoding conversions.)</sub>

<sub>The fixed sized representation itself is worthless for two reasons; first, many code points have semantic meanings and so understanding text means you have to process multiple code points anyway. Secondly, some platforms such as Windows use UTF-16 as the `wchar_t` encoding, which means a single `wchar_t` isn't even necessarily a code point value. (Whether using UTF-16 this way is even conformant to the standard is ambiguous. The standard requires that every character supported by a locale be representable as a single `wchar_t` value; If no locale supports any character outside the BMP then UTF-16 could be seen as conformant.)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

You have to start by reading the first byte or two of the stream, and
deciding whether it is part of a BOM or not.  It's a bit of a pain,
since you can only `putback` a single byte, whereas you typically will
want to read four.  The simplest solution is to open the file, read the
initial bytes, memorize how many you need to skip, then seek back to the
beginning and skip them.

Comment: The UTF8 BOM is *three* bytes long. I'm assuming the stream is byte-sized, since it's a `char`-stream, so it can't really be UTF16 or UTF32.

Comment: @KerrekSB You can read UTF-16 and UTF-32 as `char` streams, provided you have the appropriate locale.  On the other hand, I don't know what they would do with a BOM.  (IMHO, the BOM should really be the responsibility of the stream.  Or rather of the the `codecvt` facet it uses.)

Comment: I had forgotten about the locales. Do you have to write your own, or is there a UTF-16 one in the standard?

Comment: @KerrekSB The only local in the standard is "C".  For the rest, it's all implementation dependent.  For Linux, you can see what locales are available by listing `/usr/lib/locale`.  I don't know of any equivalent for Windows, however.

Answer (score 0):

With a not-so-clean solution, I solved by removing non printing chars:

```
bool isNotAlnum(unsigned char c)
{
    return (c < ' ' || c > '~');
}
```

...

```
str.erase(remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), isNotAlnum), str.end());
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple C++ function to skip the BOM on an input stream on Windows. This assumes byte-sized data, as in UTF-8:

```
// skip BOM for UTF-8 on Windows
void skip_bom(auto& fs) {
    const unsigned char boms[]{ 0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf };
    bool have_bom{ true };
    for(const auto& c : boms) {
        if((unsigned char)fs.get() != c) have_bom = false; 
    }
    if(!have_bom) fs.seekg(0);
    return;
}
```

It simply checks the first three bytes for the UTF-8 BOM signature, and skips them if they all match. There's no harm if there's no BOM.

Edit: This works with a file stream, but not with `cin`. I found it did work with `cin` on Linux with GCC-11, but that's clearly not portable. See @Dúthomhas comment below.

Comment: This question is 10 years old, and your solution assumes a seekable stream delivering byte-sized data. For example, std::cin is _not_ seekable, meaning that skip_bom() leaves the input state unsynchronized wrt what the program wants to get if the first characters are anything but a UTF-8 BOM. — The _correct_ method is to open the stream as a byte stream to identify its type, _close it_, then return a _new_ file object reading that particular stream type and returning _code points_, not byte characters.

Comment: @Dúthomhas – that makes sense – thanks. It's interesting that this works on Linux with GCC 11, and `rdstate` is 0 after the `seekg()` call. But it doesn't seem to work with Clang on macOS. I'll take your suggestion and rethink my approach.

Comment: Your approach works just fine if you open the file _temporarily_ for the _sole purpose_ of testing for a BOM. (This is actually a common approach for identifying a file’s type and format. Once the file’s type is identified, the caller can choose what to do with it.) So your function’s caller could determine that the file is a valid UTF-8 bytestream with or without a complete BOM. (A partial BOM means it is not a UTF-8.)

Comment: AFAIK, seeking back on `cin` is an implementation capability tied to compiler + OS + stream source. If `cin` is a human at the keyboard, though, there is no OS I know of that supports any kind of backwards seek. It may not report failure, but the input pointer does not actually change.

Comment: @Dúthomhas - My initial test was with a piped file. GCC/Linux must be handling that as a file stream. Anyway, I've updated the answer to explain that it's not going to work with cin. Thanks again.