# Stream reading characters that aren't in the file

Tags: c++

When I read in a file I am getting three characters being read first which aren't in the file.

They are: "ï»¿"

The file contains:

```
<root>
  <tag>
    <anothertag>Text</anothertag>
  </tag>
  <tag>
    <anothertag>Text</anothertag>
  </tag>
</root>
```

My code:

```
//scanner.h
enum TOKEN_TYPE {
    OPEN, CLOSE, TEXT
};

struct Token {
    int type;
    std::string value;
};

class Scanner {
public:
    Scanner(std::string path);

    void scan(std::string path);

private:
    std::vector<Token> tokens;

    Token readToken(std::ifstream& in);
};

std::string read_to(std::istream& in, char delim);

//scanner.cpp
Scanner::Scanner(std::string path) {
    scan(path);
}

void Scanner::scan(std::string path) {
    std::ifstream in(path, std::ios_base::beg);

    if(!in.is_open()) {
        return;
    }

    if(!tokens.empty()) {
        tokens.erase(tokens.begin(), tokens.end());
    }

    std::ofstream out("output.txt");
    while(!in.eof()) {
        tokens.push_back(readToken(in));

        if(tokens.back().value.empty()) {
            tokens.pop_back();
            continue;
        }

        out << tokens.size() << "\t" << tokens.back().value << "\t" << tokens.back().value.length() << std::endl;
    }

    in.close();

    out << "\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); ++i) {
        if(tokens[i].type == TOKEN_TYPE::TEXT) {
            out << tokens[i].value << std::endl;
        }
    }

    out.close();
}

Token Scanner::readToken(std::ifstream& in) {
    Token token;

    char c = in.get();
    while(c == '\n' || c == '\t' || c == ' ') {
        c = in.get();
    }

    if(c == '<') {
        c = in.get();

        if(c == '/') {
            token.type = TOKEN_TYPE::CLOSE;
            token.value = read_to(in, '>');
        } else {
            in.unget();

            token.type = TOKEN_TYPE::OPEN;
            token.value = read_to(in, '>');
        }
    } else {
        in.unget();

        token.type = TOKEN_TYPE::TEXT;
        token.value = read_to(in, '<');

        in.unget();
    }

    return token;
}

inline std::string read_to(std::istream& in, char delim) {
    std::stringstream str;

    char c;
    while((c = in.get()) != delim && in.good()) {
        str << c;
    }

    return str.str();
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Scanner scanner("test.xml");
    return 0;
}
```

Why is the stream reading these characters that aren't actually there?

Comment: I link this to this possible duplicate, because this is a BOM problem: [Ignore byte-order marks in C++, reading from a stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880548/ignore-byte-order-marks-in-c-reading-from-a-stream)

Comment: Sorry if this is a duplicate, I wasn't aware about BOMs until just now so I didn't know what to search for.

Comment: @Rarge: Tip: search for "ï»¿".

Comment: Also, you should learn how and when to check your stream state.  You can't check `eof()` before reading, and you shouldn't potentially use read data after an error - i.e. prefer `(c = in.get()), in.good() && c != delim`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"ï»¿" is a [UTF-8 BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Byte_order_mark). You have to skip it manually, or remove it from the file (UTF-8 doesn't really need a BOM).

Comment: But it does allow identifying it as UTF-8 (as opposed to e.g. Latin 1).  In particular, "ï»¿" is not a UTF-8 BOM; it is the bytes of a UTF-8 BOM displayed as if they were Latin 1.  (A UTF-8 BOM displays as a zero width space in UTF-8.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: It does *not* allow you to distinguish between UTF-8 and Latin 1. It lets you to recognize UTF-8, but if it's not UTF-8 you *cannot* deduce that it's Latin 1. There are plenty of other single-byte legacy encodings. You can't distinguish between them reliably without external hinting. The only *sane* way is to assume UTF-8 *everywhere* and deprecate all other single-byte encodings. This way the BOM is redundant, and in fact Unicode consortium recommends against BOMs, nor they are common in non-Windows world.

Comment: @JamesKanze: regarding your second note, please understand the difference between "X is Y" and "Y is X".

Comment: It doesn't even allow you to be 100% sure that it's UTF-8.  A Latin 1 file could start with "ï»¿".  It's a fairly good heuristic, however: if the first three bytes of the file are 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF, then it's _probably_ UTF-8.  If they're not, and there are no 0x00 in the first four bytes, nor a 0xFF or 0xFE, you're reduced to guessing---in the environments I work in, ISO 8859-1, aka as Latin 1, is probably the best guess (although ISO 8859-15, aka Latin 9 is gaining ground, because of the Euro).

Comment: And please understand that "ï»¿" and a UTF-8 BOM are two different things, that just happen to have the same numeric values for the three bytes each contains:-).  (The way you have expressed it is a convenient shorthand, but not technically correct.)